# Can CSS detect and move and HTML element when a distant child class is present?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Attempting to move an off-screen panel on screen based on the presence of child CSS selector (added/removed dynamically).

What am I doing wrong? TIA

Scenario:

An off-screen panel `.details` with CSS rule watching for a child selector `.finished-loading`. When child selector is present (loaded dynamically via end-user interaction), the panel’s CSS rule becomes true and the `.details` panel slides on screen.

Example : :

CSS:

```
body .details {margin-right: -300px;} /* .details panel is closed */
body.show-details .details .finished-loading {margin-right: 0;} /* conditions on opening the .details panel */
```

HTML:

```
<body class=".show-details">
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="details">
    <!-- any number of nested elements -->
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Dynamically loaded content</p>
        <p class="finished-loading">Dynamically loaded content</p> <!-- .finished-loading triggers CSS rule -->
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

So many errors...

1. Add the class to control the margin to the details div or the body
2. Dont use margin, use transform - its processed after the html engine did the positioning/layoutig and will produce a nicer animation if you use transitions.
3. classnames must not have dots at any position

```html
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="details finished-loading">
    <!-- any number of nested elements -->
    <div>
      <div>
        <p>Dynamically loaded content</p>
        <p>Dynamically loaded content</p>
      </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

```
.details {transition: transform .5s ease;}
.details:not(.finished-loading) {transform: translateX(300px);}
```

The example uses the negation pseudo-class (:not), this way the code is a little shorter. You could also do it like this, easier to understand, but more code:

```css
.details {transition: transform .5s ease;transform: translateX(300px);}
.details.finished-loading {transform: translateX(0);}
```

**Edit:**

Some explanation, why you need to add the class to the details div or the body:

It is currently not possible to select an element via a child-constraint (except :empty).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Appreciate the explanation. The `.details` panel is the last in a series of panels using Flexbox. So they are side by side. 

Example: 
[https://dragontheory.com/holygrail09](https://dragontheory.com/holygrail09)

When I swapped out the margins for transforms, the `.details` panel overlapped the adjacent panel rather than pushing it. I had been using flex-basis but for the lack of support in IE11 I had to use width. Is transform ideal to work with Flexbox? 

Thanks again.

Comment: I thought you want to achieve some kind of off-canvas effect. Did you think about using absolute positioning to move the details pane one level above the list?

Comment: Yes, off screen affect but using Flexbox. Needs to push content, not overlap.